# Rails >= 3.0.8 render inline code with layout not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

It seems the render method has changed. 
In the view I used to be able to do the following:

```
= render :layout => 'some_layout' do
  some stuff to be rendered
```

It seems the best fix is to move the content into a partial and call the layout

```
= render :partial => 'some stuff to be rendered', :layout => 'some_layout'
```

I was just wondering if anyone had come across this and if it is a bug or an intended change?

---

EDIT

Rendering a block inline with a layout works. Check out the part about applying a layout to a block within any template at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html

The issue I am having is with the latest version of HAML not rendering nested render calls properly.
    https://github.com/nex3/haml/issues/412

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the most recent version of HAML v3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

From your post, it appears you are trying to do this in a view.

Is it possible that you are confusing `ActionController`'s render and `ActionView`'s render?  Looking @ the API documentation for 2.3.8 & 3.x, it doesn't seem there was ever a `:layout` option within `ActionView`'s render.

---

UPDATE

Actually, I may have been off-base.  It does seem that there is an `:inline` option as described [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Rendering.html#method-i-render).

> **render(options = {}, locals = {}, &block)**
>
> Returns the result of a
>   render that’s dictated by the options hash. The primary options are:
>
> - :partial - See ActionView::Partials.
> - :update - Calls update_page with the block given.
> - :file - Renders an explicit template file (this used to be the old default), add :locals to pass in those.
> - **:inline - Renders an inline template similar to how it’s done in the controller.**
> - :text - Renders the text passed in out.

Comment: I'm confused - your first answer was about no `:layout` in ActionView#render and your follow-up was about `:inline`. While there is a case for nested templates, this is achieved by `:layout` being the top-level template and `:partial`s used elsewhere.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.  I was making an assumption that the `:inline` option accomplished what the OP was trying to do using the seemingly non-existent `:layout` option in the view.